# Instruction to reopen doesn't include "post at meta"

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, reopening

My impression across SE stacks is that questions get put on hold and almost never get voted to reopen. Can we have a disclaimer on closed question that gives hope to the OP, that says something like:

> put on hold as too broad by [...] 10 hours ago
>   Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough
>   detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct
>   questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this
>   question. If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the
>   help center, please edit the question.
>   **After editing, you can post on meta to request reopen, please use tag `reopen-request`**

Comment: I've seen questions in the reopen queue with the comment "This question was edited after it was put on hold" (or similar - there aren't any there now for me to check the exact wording). I was under the impression that these were added to the queue automatically, does a person have to nominate them before they get there?

Answer (score 7):

The usual process is for them to edit, which puts it into the reopen review queue. Posting on meta should not be necessary.

Maybe giving guidance to edit is all that is needed.

See this answer over on the main meta.SE:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215375/154443

> There are multiple ways you can draw attention to a closed post:
>
> Editing a closed post will result in it appearing in the re-open review queue for people who can reopen posts.
>
> You could flag the post with a custom reason to get a moderator to look at but this is not the preferred method to gain attention to your post.

Comment: ok so it is high-rep people responsibility to reopen questions? I was hoping we can give people some hope that question on hold can be reopened

Comment: On many sites there is an active community that reopens questions really quickly. The review queue works - however the post will need to have whatever caused it to be closed sorted, otherwise the reviewers will say no. And it is definitely not high rep users: it's anyone over 3k rep for graduated sites.